# Print without printing dialogue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, printing

I know someones will say that there is a too many links opening such kind of problem but none of them worked.

I have this website: http://windory.club/locres/
when people selecting some products at the top of the website in the basket field is written (number) goods. When you click there there is an option to print. When you click print it shows print dialogue, which I dont want...

I just want to print imediately after click on default printer...

Comment: Then I imagine your users would need to install a browser plugin or local application or some sort.  In-browser JavaScript doesn't access the printer (or anything else outside of the browser), it requests the browser to do it via a common API.  When it requests that the browser print something, that results in the print dialog.  Have you seen any examples anywhere which demonstrate that what you want to do is possible at all?

Comment: It works that way intentionally. Would you want every web site you visit spewing reams of paper out every time you clicked on that page and have no control over it?

Comment: @charlietfl Like fax, but gratis.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good reason for the print dialogue. So that the user can review the print layout and more importantly not start a print job when an accidental click has happened. Is there a reason why you want to circumvent these restrictions and don't follow common human-computer-interaction guidelines?

As for the question i have to admit, that i don't know a solution to the problem, but can imagine that at least with javascript there will be no possibility (for said above reasons).
PHP is a server language, so you will not be able to execute a print command on the users computer.

Edit: On Second Thought: Do you want to print the basket at your(!) computer?

Comment: The main reason why I want to print like this is I'm using this website for restaurant printing and it's hard for clients to do additional printing functions...